# Taking the derivative of a definite integral with respect to a different variable

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been looking through the textbook for the Differential Equations class I'll be taking next semester, and I came across the following problem in the first section:

*Verify that the indicated family of functions is a solution of the given differential equation. Assume an appropriate interval I of definition for each solution.*

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = 1; y = e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt + c_{1}e^{-x^{2}} $$

I'm struggling on multiple levels with this problem, but let me first lay out what I've done. I first tried to solve the integral, but failed using all of the methods I know. I then tried to just take the derivative of y and hope that the integral just kind of sorts itself out. I did as follows:

Let $f(t) = e^{t^{2}}$

Then $ F(t) = \int f(t) dt $.

So then we have $ y = e^{-x^{2}}F(x) - e^{-x^{2}}F(0) + c_{1}e^{-x^{2}} $

And $ y' = -2xe^{-x^{2}}F(x) + e^{-x^{2}}f(x) +2xe^{-x^{2}}F(0) + e^{-x^{2}}f(0) -2c_{1}xe^{-x^{2}}$

But I got stuck here, because I have no way of finding $F(x)$ or $F(0)$.

Finally, I did a lot of searching through this site, though I wasn't sure exactly what the terminology for this exercise was. I came across a few examples that looked promising, but they all involved methods I have never been taught, such as the 'Leibniz Rule'.

Also, on the conceptual level, I'm struggling to imagine what the derivative with respect to x of a definite integral with a variable other than x.

Would someone please explain not just the steps, but the reasoning behind them, for solving this problem? Also, apologies for any bad LaTeX formatting. I'm still learning.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Ok, so I've gotten up to this point:

$$ y' = -2xe^{-x^{2}}F(x) + 2xe^{-x^{2}}F(0) + e^{-x^{2}}f(x) - e^{-x^{2}}f(0) - 2c_{1}xe^{-x^{2}} $$

$$ y' = -2xe^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt - e^{-x^{2}} + 1 $$

And plugging in $y$ and $y'$ gives me

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = [-2xe^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt - e^{-x^{2}} + 1 - 2c_{1}xe^{-x^{2}}] + 2x[e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt + c_{1}e^{-x^{2}}] $$

$$ = -2xe^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt - e^{-x^{2}} + 1 + 2c_{1}xe^{-x^{2}} + 2xe^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt + 2xc_{1}e^{-x^{2}} $$

$$ = 1 - e^{-x^{2}} \neq 1 $$

Where did I go wrong?

**Edit 2:** Or, did I screw up when I used the product rule above? Since $f$ is technically a function of $t$, is $\frac{d}{dx}F(t=x)$ equal to $f(x)$ or $0$?

Comment: Wasn't the second FTOC what I used in the example above, breaking the integral up into $F(x) - F(0)$? In doing so I got stuck, because I had no way of solving for $F(x)$ or $F(0)$.

Comment: yeah, sorry....

Comment: but anyway, solving the problem doesn't mean "computing" F(x) (I think there is no way to write $F(x)$ without an integral sign, in some sense which I don't actually understand) - it just means checking that the equation is true when you plug in that choice of $y$.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still as to what to do with the terms involving $F(x)$ and $F(0)$. They both have the same sign coefficient, so I can't group them back into an integral via $F(a) - F(b)$. Is there a special type of integral for when you have $F(a) + F(b)$?

Comment: don't do anything with them for now. Plug in that choice of y to 2xy and then add and then hopefully the F's will cancel.

Comment: Oh okay! I just worked it out, and I see where it's going. I was getting to caught up trying to 'solve' everything, before plugging in $y'$. Curse of being in lower division, I guess.

Comment: Notice that writing $F(t) = \int f(t) \,dt$ does not completely define $F$; it only defines $F$ up to a constant.  So to nail down $F$, you may pick one value $t_0$ of $t$ and choose $F(t_0)$ to be whatever you wish.  Under the circumstances, since $F(0)$ comes up, you should probably use $t_0 = 0$.  And you can make dealing with $F(0)$ as simple as possible by choosing $F(0) = 0$ too.  In that case, $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt = F(x) - F(0)$ becomes simply $F(x)$.

Comment: (In fact, normally people will not go through all of this business with the indefinite integral up to a constant; they'll just say ‘Let $F(x)$ be $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt$.’ and leave it at that.  But in either case, the important facts about $F$ are that $F'(t) = f(t)$ for all $t$, and that $F(0) = 0$.)

Comment: "I was getting to caught up trying to 'solve' everything" <-- also a problem of mine. sometimes you gotta leave your problems as F(x) and hope they cancel.

Comment: So I tried to finish up the problem, and I came out with the wrong answer again. I saw where the antiderivatives canceled, but I'm still left over with an extra term besides 1 in my final solution. I edited my post to show the work. I have no idea what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to solve the equation, but just to check those functions are solutions. Set
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\,dt
$$
and differentiate $y=ce^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\,dt=ce^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}f(x)$:
$$
y'=-2cxe^{-x^2}-2xe^{-x^2}f(x)+e^{-x^2}f'(x)=-2cxe^{-x^2}-2xe^{-x^2}f(x)+1
$$
and so
$$
y'+2xy=-2cxe^{-x^2}-2xe^{-x^2}f(x)+1+2x(ce^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}f(x))=1
$$
as desired.

Check your steps with this computation and you'll find your mistake.

---

You can also prove that *every* solution has that form.

The equation can be written $y'+2xy=1$. Set $y=e^{-x^2}z$, so
$$
y'=-2xe^{-x^2}z+e^{-x^2}z'
$$
and substituting in the equation yields
$$
-2xe^{-x^2}z+e^{-x^2}z'+2xe^{-x^2}z=1
$$
that is,
$$
z'=e^{x^2}
$$
A solution of this equation is clearly
$$
z=c+\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\,dt
$$
for some constant $c$. You don't “compute” this integral (in terms of “elementary functions”). Why $0$ as the lower bound? It's completely irrelevant: the fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\,dt
$$
has $f'(x)=e^{x^2}$, so any other function having the same derivative differs from $f$ by an additive constant. Choosing a different lower bound would only change $c$, which is an arbitrary constant. Since $y=e^{-x^2}z$, you get
$$
y=ce^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\,dt
$$
as the general solution of the given differential equation.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response! When you differentiate, I'm having difficulting seeing how you make the simplification from $e^{-x^{2}}f(x)$ to $1$.

Comment: @CookieToast It's $e^{-x^2}f'(x)=1$, because, by the FTC, $f'(x)=e^{x^2}$.

Comment: And the fact that $f$ is a definite integral doesn't matter? What happens to the lower integration boundary at $0$?

Comment: @CookieToast Please, review the FTC. Anyway, $f(0)=0$, so it doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: Yeah, but doesnt $f'(0) = 1$? Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here...it's been a while since I've had a proper look at the FTC.

Comment: @CookieToast Where does $f'(0)$ come from?

Comment: My apologies, my comment above should have been that I was struggling to see how you got $e^{-x^{2}}f'(x) = 1$ Should I move this to chat? I'm still new to this site, sorry.

Comment: @CookieToast $f'(x)=e^{x^2}$; therefore $e^{-x^2}f'(x)=e^{-x^2}e^{x^2}=e^{-x^2+x^2}=e^0=1$.

Comment: Ah, crap. I see it now. For an integral with an upper limit as a variable, the FTC allows us to evaluate the derivative at the upper variable, in this case $x$, regardless of the lower limit. So in your steps above, you merely need to evaluate $f'$ at $x$, and the value of $f'(0)$ is obsolete. Does that sound correct?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)-f(0)) \ne f'(x) - f'(0)$. Rather since $f(0)$ is a constant, its derivative is zero

Comment: Also, *by definition*, $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $y(x)=e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt+c_1e^{-x^2}$, then

$$\begin{align}
y'(x)&=\color{blue}{-2xe^{-x^2} \int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt} +\color{red}{e^{-x^2}e^{x^2}}-2xc_1e^{-x^2}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{-2x( y(x)-c_1e^{-x^2})}+\color{red}{1}-2xc_1e^{-x^2}\\\\
&=-2xy+1
\end{align}$$

Comment: When you differentiate to get $y'$, shouldn't there also be a term $-e^{-x^{2}}e^{0^{2}} = -e^{-x^{2}}$, since you have to evaluate the derivative of the integral at both $F(x)$ and $F(0)$?

Comment: No.  The derivative of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Could you explain the process and or provide more steps/details? This problem as a whole is relatively unfamiliar to me, and I'm struggling to make the jumps in your steps.

Comment: Apply the product rule and appy the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct since it satisfies the differential equation. Solutions to some differential equations are expressed as integrals. Numerical analysis comes to rescue if a specific value is desired.